# Retrieving YouTube Channel insights though API

Tags: java, youtube-api, gdata-api, youtube-channels

i'm using code below to get link for my channels insight data.
somehow my code is returning null as Link.

/***** code*********/

```
public static final String FEED_URL =  "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/mychannelname/uploads";  //i put my channel's name in 'mychannelname'

String username = "mygmailid";    //here i entered my gmail id eg. mikeme@gmail.com
String password = "mypassword";
String developerKey = "AI39si7ffVeKWbG1k37***********************************************" //developer key

YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService( username  ,developerKey);  //just put username instead of clientid since client id no longer available
try {
    service.setUserCredentials(username, password);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid login credentials.");
    System.exit(1);
    }

Query query = null;
try { 
    query = new Query(new URL( FEED_URL)); 
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
    //TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

ChannelFeed channelFeed = null;

try { 
    channelFeed = service.query(query, ChannelFeed.class); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    System.out.println(channelFeed.getEntries() + ":"); 
    System.out.println(" Link : "+channelFeed.getLink("http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#insight.views", "text/html") + ":");
```

/*****************END*********************/

i'm getting null as Link here

can anyone help me here to find what went wrong here?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely returning null because it can't find a link corresponding to the relative name you provided. Since the channel Insight information is only available for the channel corresponding to the user you're authenticated with it could be that it is not authorizing your user to view that channels insight data, which could be because your google account is not linked with your youtube account.

I would try printing out the response you're getting back to make sure you're getting all the data you think you're getting.

Comment: Hi thanks for looking into the issue,

I've access to feeds through UI login and the dev key is correct one.

here are the std outs of my results:

System.out.println(channelFeed.getEntries() + ":");
[com.google.gdata.data.youtube.ChannelEntry@413ffc, com.google.gdata.data.youtube.ChannelEntry@1cfc2c0, ....etc]

System.out.println(" Link : "+channelFeed.getLink("http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#insight.views", "text/html") + ":");
Link : null:

System.out.println(channelFeed);
com.google.gdata.data.youtube.ChannelFeed@1239010

can u verify 'FEED_URL' used in the code is exact one?

-Mike

Comment: I don't know for sure which URL  you want to use for FEED_URL, but have you tried it with `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default` and `https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username` (replacing 'username' in the second one with your username). It might be that the insight information is sent over with the user profile information and not the channel information, which is what it looks like you're requesting now.

Comment: i have changed the code as below:
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(clienID,developerKey);
query = new Query(new URL("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username"));
profileFeed = service.query(query, ProfileFeed.class);
System.out.println(profileFeed.getEntries() + ":"); 
System.out.println(" Link : "+profileFeed.getLink("http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#insight.views", "text/html") + ":");
System.out.println(profileFeed);

but i'm still getting error..:(
-Mike